# Where is kaggle_data？I could not find such a library

Tags: python-3.x, kaggle

Recently,I have been studying on this net https://github.com/leriomaggio/deep-learning-keras-tensorflow/blob/master/2.%20Deep%20Learning%20Frameworks/2.3%20Introduction%20to%20Keras.ipynb.
  In the part of Data Preparation,there is a code "from kaggle_data import load_data, preprocess_data, preprocess_labels" and I could not find such library on the net.Who can help me solve this problem???  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like that module was written by a the author. It's in the the same directory as the notebook in the GitHub repo: https://github.com/leriomaggio/deep-learning-keras-tensorflow/tree/master/2.%20Deep%20Learning%20Frameworks